# How can I create a toggle button for Greasemonkey scripts?

Tags: javascript, button, greasemonkey

So I'm trying to figure out how to make a toggle button for a greasemonkey extensions that runs and navigates to various pages.

So this is what I have so far

```
var keepgoing = true
```

*Beginnign of if statement and stuff here*

```
else if keepgoing == true
  { newsearch(); }
```

Button click:

```
 if keepgoing == true { keepgoing = false }
 else if keepgoing == false { keepgoing = true }
```

So basically I need help have a button put on a webpage.
and it needs to remember the var as it navigates through pages.

Thanks, Ray

Comment: Actually any way to create a setting page so I can change variables would work, it doesn't have to be a button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a persistent button (or any data), you'll need to use some kind of storage.  If multiple domains are involved, use [GM_setValue()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue).  If everything's on the same domain, use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#localStorage).

I add this kind of persistent button myself, here is a pared down-script that shows what I use. It doesn't just add a button, it makes the button UI a little more user-friendly, IMO.

**NOTE:**

1. The button state persists across page loads and across sites.
2. The button stays in the upper left (set by CSS) and fades to near opaque when not moused over.
3. I use an object, because I sometimes have more than 1 control that I add to page(s).
4. You can [**see a demo of how the button appears and behaves at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YGuLN/). (Except that values cannot persist across page-loads in the demo. They do in the GM script.)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Keep going button
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER_1.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER_2.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Add the button.
$("body").append (
      '<div class="gmPersistentButton">'
    + '<button id="gmContinueBtn">Init failed!</button></div>'
);

//--- Define and init the matching control object:
var btnControl  = new PersistentButton (
    "gmContinueBtn",        //-- HTML id
    "StopContinueBtn",      //-- Storage label
    ["Stop", "Continue"],   //-- Text that the button cycles through
    [false, true]           //-- Matching values for the button's states
);

//--- Activate the button click-handler.
$("#gmContinueBtn").click ( function () {
    var btnValue    = this.value;
    keepgoing       = btnValue
    btnControl.SetNextValue ();

    if (keepgoing == "true") {
        // CALL YOUR FUNCTION HERE.
    }
} );

//--- The button will fade when we aren't using it.
var zDisplayPanel   = $('div.gmPersistentButton');
zDisplayPanel.hover (
    function () { $(this).stop (true, false).fadeTo (50,  1  ); },
    function () { $(this).stop (true, false).fadeTo (900, 0.1); }
);
zDisplayPanel.fadeTo (2900, 0.1);


//--- CSS styles to make it work and to improve appearance.
GM_addStyle ( (<><![CDATA[
    .gmPersistentButton {
        background:         orange;
        color:              black;
        position:           fixed;
        top:                1em;
        right:              1em;
        z-index:            6666;
        padding:            1em;
        border:             3px double gray;
        border-radius:      1ex;
        opacity:            0.8;
    }
    .gmPersistentButton button {
        cursor:             pointer;
    }
    .gmPersistentButton button:hover {
        color:              red;
    }
]]></>).toString () );


//--- Button object
function PersistentButton (htmlID, setValName, textArry, valueArry) {
    //--- Initialize the button to last stored value or default.
    var buttonValue     = valueArry[0];
    fetchValue ();
    storeValue ();      //-- Store, in case it wasn't already.
    setButtonTextAndVal ();

    //--- DONE with init.  Set click and keyboard listeners externally.

    //***** Public functions:
    this.Reset          = function () {
        buttonValue     = valueArry[0];
        storeValue ();    
        setButtonTextAndVal ();
    };

    this.SetNextValue   = function () {
        var numValues   = valueArry.length;
        var valIndex    = 0;

        for (var J = numValues - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
            if (buttonValue == valueArry[J]) {
                valIndex    = J;
                break;
            }
        }
        valIndex++;
        if (valIndex >= numValues)
            valIndex    = 0;

        buttonValue     = valueArry[valIndex];

        storeValue ();    
        setButtonTextAndVal ();
    };


    //***** Private functions:
    function fetchValue () {
        buttonValue     = GM_getValue (setValName, buttonValue);
    }

    function storeValue () {
        GM_setValue (setValName, buttonValue);
    }

    function setButtonTextAndVal () {
        var buttonText  = "*ERROR!*";

        for (var J = valueArry.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
            if (buttonValue == valueArry[J]) {
                buttonText  = textArry[J];
                break;
            }
        }

        var theBtn      = document.getElementById (htmlID);
        if (theBtn) {
            theBtn.textContent  = buttonText;
            theBtn.setAttribute ("value", buttonValue);
        }
        else
            alert ('Missing persistent button with ID: ' + htmlID + '!');
    }
}
```

Comment: nitpick, opaque is the opposite of transparent